# How to get short process name(cmd argument) in ps command of ps -eo pid,ppid,%mem,%cpu,cmd --sort=-%mem | head

Tags: linux, ps

Executing the command

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,%mem,%cpu,cmd --sort=-%mem | head
```

I get:

```
   PID    PPID %MEM %CPU CMD
   1555       1  4.2  0.2 /usr/sbin/mysqld
   2989    2735  3.9  4.0 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
   4785    2735  3.8  3.3 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
   5053    4803  3.6  1.4 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=14183456324498441308,5334468187998544589,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=e482c1e6-5c57-40e8-bb27-910eab6576d7, --extension-process --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=12 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
   5054    4803  3.5  0.6 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=14183456324498441308,5334468187998544589,131072 --lang=en-GB --enable-crash-reporter=e482c1e6-5c57-40e8-bb27-910eab6576d7, --extension-process --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=13 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
```

In the output above, I only want to see `chrome` or `opt/google/chrome/chrome` and not the complete name.

Answer (score 0):

According to the **STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS** section of the [ps man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), the `cmd` keyword is an alias for the `args` keyword which will display the command with all its arguments. Use the `comm` keyword instead, which will display only the command name.

`ps -eo pid,ppid,%mem,%cpu,comm --sort=-%mem | head`

If the command name is not fully displayed, you may also use the width specifier, to specify the exact number of characters displayed (won't make any difference if `comm` is your last column)

`ps -eo pid,ppid,%mem,%cpu,comm:20 --sort=-%mem | head`

Comment: Thanks a lot man !  I am getting the desired output .